# What can I say to my boss when I haven't got pay

Tags: tense, phrase-request

When I haven't got pay, can I say to my boss

> You still don't pay

is this correct?
Please tell me what I can say.

Comment: You still **haven't paid** me!

Answer (score 4):

Possible things to say are

> **You still haven't paid me.**

or

> **I haven't been paid.**

or

> **I haven't received my pay.**

(Thanks to @CopperKettle for the first one!)
You will notice that all of these use the *present perfect*.  This is an appropriate choice because the situation of "not being paid" is something that continues from the past to the present.

If you use the present tense "you don't", it sounds like you're talking about a general situation, as though your boss *never* pays you.